# passing in args[] or missing args in java

Tags: java, file, arguments, external

I am writing code for an assignment in class, and have never actually used scanner in this way.   However when I rum the below code I get the errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at World.<init>(World.java:20)
at World.main(World.java:58)
```

I guess I'm just confused since I have eclipse using the world text file to create, it's just not allowing it.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

 /*************************************************************************
* Name        :  
* Username    : 
* Description :      *************************************************************************/

 public class World{
//instance variables
String mapFile; //This holds the .txt name that contains the map.
Tile[][] worldMap;

public World(String mapFile){
    this.mapFile = mapFile;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(mapFile);
    //get the dimensions of the world
    int width = scanner.nextInt();
    int height = scanner.nextInt();
    int x_coor = scanner.nextInt();
    int y_coor = scanner.nextInt();
    //initialize the array to proper height and width
    worldMap = new Tile[width][height];
    //set the starting locations of the avatar character
    Avatar avatar = new Avatar(x_coor, y_coor);
    //populate the worldMap
    for(int i = 0; i < worldMap.length - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; i <worldMap[0].length -1; j++){
            worldMap[i][j] = new Tile(scanner.next());
        }
    }


}
//draw the map
public void draw(){
    for(int i = 0; i < worldMap.length - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < worldMap[0].length -1; i++){
            worldMap[i][j].draw(i, j);
        }
    }
}







// Test method


public static void main(String [] args)
{       


    World world = new World(args[0]);
    world.draw();       
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You constructed your `Scanner` around a `String` (not around a `File`). Change this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(mapFile);
```

to

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(mapFile));
```

right now the `Scanner` is scanning your `String` *filename*.